# Discord.js V13: How do I get/ find a category?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to find a category just like how you find a channel.

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(<id>);
```

Is there a way to find a category like this? I am trying to see if a specific category exists, and if it does not, it will create a category. I also want to find the category with a name and not an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It same with channels because categories are type of channel.

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type == "GUILD_CATEGORY" && channel.name == "xxx")

// this returns you category with this name if exists.
```